# center div vertically jumping in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have created a script to keep a div centred on the screen. It works fine in safari but for some reason jumps on window resize. I assume is is doubling the negative 'margin-top'. Anyone have any experience with this. I havent tried in chrome or ie.

```
// PART B
function cent() {
var $block = $("#block"),
    margintop = parseInt($block.height() / -2);
console.log('called');
$('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
cent();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
cent();
});
```

the site url:
www.thebackroads.com.au

Comment: Looks fine on load. then jumps up approx 50px when i resize the window

Comment: sorry. skips DOWN approx 50px

Answer (score 1):

If you log `$block.height()` You will see the javascript generated margin-top at load differs from the one when resizing because it seems your container actually has a different height.

This is probably due to the first `cent()` call being done when DOM isn't fully loaded. Or at least the text container hasn't reached it's final height because you show a preloader while image is being loaded. The reason for this is probably your external library. See [DOM not fully loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144474/dom-not-fully-loaded)

You can see this clearly in firebug your content is hidden when you calculate the height.

[image]

Read some solutions here:

[jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Do you think it might be calculating the height before the web-font loads?

Comment: Edit made, One thing for certain is you calculate when the content is hidden. See screenshot.

Comment: I think ive fixed it. Ive replaced `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$(window).bind("load", function(){` do you think this will cause any problems?

Comment: on second thoughts, this seems to have messed it up more.

Comment: best bet is to start calculating when your text is actually shown on screen. So do a method call when your image is loaded or whenever in the script your text shows.

Answer (score 0):

Or try this script? Calculate with window's height.

```
function cent() {
    var margintop = ($(window).height() - $('#block').height()) / 2;
    $('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
};
```